# I am getting this error when i am starting cassandra server

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

[root@SudeepMangu bin]# ./cassandra -f

xss =  -ea -javaagent:/home/sudeep/apache-cassandra-1.2.5-src/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms930M -Xmx930M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss160k

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:** **org/apache/cassandra/service/CassandraDaemon**
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
**Could not find the main class: org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.  Program will exit.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting you are starting the server under windows.

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

You are getting this exception because you haven't set the `CASSANDRA_HOME` variable, so when you start the server you are trying to find the path to Cassandra but you cant, because that path is constructed using that environment variable.

Simply add the system variable:

```
setx CASSANDRA_HOME "C:\path\to\cassandra\"    // Windows
export CASSANDRA_HOME=/path/to/cassandra/      // Unix
```

Just a heads up doing this in the `cmd` will require you to open a new prompt.You can also do it using the [GUI approach](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/) in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have an administrative privileges then you might want to add it to the cassandra.bat file as

```
set CASSANDRA_HOME="C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-1.2.8"
```